# cleaning all characters from terminal

Tags: c, terminal, whitespace

```
 void clearscreen ( void )
 {       
        char a = 'a' ;
              fflush ( stdout ); 
        do{
               a = getc( stdin )   ;

               if ( isspace ( (int ) a ) )
                       { 
                       getc ( stdin ); 
                       }

            }while ( a != EOF ); 


 }
```

**I** *want* write function which is capable of cleaning the screen, while doing its job it **must** erase all characters including especially **whitespace** characters.
   But I could not write it, so are there any one can help me to write such a function

Comment: Please format your code correctly!  use the "1010" button in the editor.

Comment: There is a stray back tick (`) in your code. Also, what is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by erasing whitespace characters on a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with a ANSI-compliant terminal (which is probably the case if you're under Linux), then you can use [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).